# Sleep Tracking and Analysis with Apple Healthkit

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I'm building an application for sleep analysis using Apple Healthkit and wish to retrieve nightly sleep statistics (time in REM, deep, light etc). The apple developer video gives the following code to retrieve samples in all sleep stages...

```
let stagePredicate = HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.predicateForSamples(equalTo: .allAsleepValues)

let queryPredicate = HKSamplePredicate.sample(type: HKCategoryType(.sleepAnalysis), predicate: stagePredicate)

let sleepQuery = HKSampleQueryDescriptor(predicates: [queryPredicate], sortDescriptors: [])

// Run the query
let sleepSamples = try async sleepQuery.result(for: healthStore)
```

but how do I compute the time in each of the stages for the previous night? I'm very new to healthkit so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the time in each stage you'll want to iterate over the samples and check the category value.  You can keep a time interval per stage and increment it based on the duration of the sample you're looking at.

The tricky part is determining what "previous night" is.  Try defining equally sized buckets where you will count all samples in that bucket as part of the same "sleep session" (e.g. 6pm - 6pm instead of 12am - 12am).

Comment: can you give the code to get the duration of the sample? I'm pretty unfamiliar with the healthkit syntax

Comment: also if I don't define a "previous night", will it give the samples from every night?

Comment: The point about "previous night" is that it's a very subtle question of what period of time "the previous night" covers. For example, what if someone works at night and sleeps during the day? Is there a difference between a "nap" and "sleep?" If they sleep from 4p-7p and then from 3a-7a, when and how long was "the previous night's sleep?" What if they've been awake for over 24 hours? What if the user changes time zones? What if they cross the international date line? It seems an easy thing to define, but it's a very challenging. You have to decide what makes sense for *your* app.

Comment: print("sleep: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate)")

The duration is the time between the two dates.

Comment: Check out apple docs on HealthKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksample/